# html5 server sent events EventSource not recognized

Tags: jquery, html, generic-handler

I am trying to create a demo project with HTML5 server sent events, I have created a generic handler that will generate data (random numbers) to be sent to the client side. I have also created a webform (.aspx) page to be the client. I wrote javascript that was meant to get the handler run the function and return data to the front end to be populated to a div tag. The problem that I am running into is that when I am running the program its Stops on:
   var source = new EventSource('SSEHandler.ashx'); complaining that The EventSource is not recognized. I am pretty new to HTML 5 server sent events so I am not sure what is needed for the event source to be recognized but this is the Client code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Client.aspx.cs" :

Inherits="Client" %>
```

:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org:

/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

:

```
<head runat="server">
<title>Server Sent Events</title>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var data = [];
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#btnListen").click(function () {
            var source = new EventSource('SSEHandler.ashx');
            source.addEventListener("open", function (event) {
                $('#headerDiv').append('Latest 5 values');
            }, false);


            source.addEventListener("error", function (event) {
                if (event.eventPhase == EventSource.CLOSED) { :
                     $('#footerDiv').append('Connection Closed!'); }
            }, false);

            source.addEventListener("message", function (event) {
                if (data.length >= 5) { data = data.slice(1); }
                data.push(event.data);
                var strData = '';
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    strData += data[i] + '<br/>';
                }
                $('#targetDiv').hide();
                $('#targetDiv').empty();
                $('#targetDiv').html(strData);
                $('#targetDiv').slideDown(1000);
            }, false);
        });
    });
</script>
```

:

```
</head>
```

:

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<button id="btnListen">Start Listening</button> 
<!-- <button id="Button1" value="Start Listening">Start Listening</button> -->
<br /><br />
<div id="headerDiv" class="tickerheading"></div>
<div id="targetDiv" class="ticker"></div>
<div id="footerDiv" class="tickerfooter"></div>
</form>
```

:

```
</body>
```

:

```
</html>
```

Comment: What browser are you using? Not all browsers support EventSource http://caniuse.com/eventsource

Comment: I am using i.e. but I'll take the url as localhost and use it in firefox

Comment: IE doesn't support HTML5 SSE